# FileOpenPicker not working in C# on Windows 11 Desktop

Tags: visual-studio, windows-11, uno, fileopenpicker

I am creating a Windows Form App in VS on Windows11 and get this error when I attempt to run my file picker function:
System.NotImplementedException: 'The member IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList> FileOpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync() is not implemented in Uno.'

The Code :

```
        var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        var files = await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();     
        if(files!=null){//stuff n things}
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 has its own method for opening files. FilePicker will not work in the new App environtment.

[How To Open Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-open-files-using-the-openfiledialog-component?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)